# Convert Sequential to Functional in Keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, keras, lstm

I have a keras code written in Sequential style. But I am trying to switch `Functional mode` because I want to use `merge` function. But I faced an error below when declaring `Model(x, out)`. What is wrong in my Functional API code?

```
# Sequential, this is working
# out_size==16, seq_len==1
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(128, 
               input_shape=(seq_len, input_dim),
               activation='tanh', 
               return_sequences=True))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(out_size, activation='softmax')))

# Functional API
x = Input((seq_len, input_dim))
lstm = LSTM(128, return_sequences=True, activation='tanh')(x)
td = TimeDistributed(Dense(out_size, activation='softmax'))(lstm)
out = merge([td, Input((seq_len, out_size))], mode='mul')
model = Model(input=x, output=out) # error below
```

> RuntimeError: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor
>   Tensor("input_40:0", shape=(?, 1, 16), dtype=float32) at layer
>   "input_40". The following previous layers were accessed without issue:
>   ['input_39', 'lstm_37']

### Updated

Thank you @Marcin Możejko. I finally did it.

```
x = Input((seq_len, input_dim))
lstm = LSTM(128, return_sequences=True, activation='tanh')(x)
td = TimeDistributed(Dense(out_size, activation='softmax'))(lstm)
second_input = Input((seq_len, out_size)) # object instanciated and hold as a var.
out = merge([td, second_input], mode='mul')
model = Model(input=[x, second_input], output=out) # second input provided to model.compile(...)

# then I add two inputs
model.fit([trainX, filter], trainY, ...)
```

Comment: what are you trying to do with merge([td , input((seq_len,out_size))],...) ? you want to have a second input in your model?  explain a bit more what you are trying to achieve and we will help you code it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One may notice that reference of an object created by a `Input((seq_len, out_size))` call is accesible only from `merge` funciton call evironment. Moreover - it's not add to a `Model` definition - what makes graph disconnected. What you need to do is:

```
x = Input((seq_len, input_dim))
lstm = LSTM(128, return_sequences=True, activation='tanh')(x)
td = TimeDistributed(Dense(out_size, activation='softmax'))(lstm)
second_input = Input((seq_len, out_size)) # object instanciated and hold as a var.
out = merge([td, second_input], mode='mul')
model = Model(input=[x, second_input], output=out) # second input provided to model
```