# My Sequential model's performance is worse than Functional one in Keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, keras, lstm

Yesterday, I could finally implement my model in Keras. But for my study, I want to implement my model in `Sequential` and `Functional`.
[Convert Sequential to Functional in Keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42804966/convert-sequential-to-functional-in-keras)

My `Functional` is actually working well. On the other hand, `Sequential` works, but the accuracy is quite worse than `Functional`.

Could you find any mistakes in my `Sequential` model?

```
if is_sequential:
    # Sequential, working
    x = Sequential()
    x.add(LSTM(128, 
               input_shape=(seq_len, input_dim),
               activation='tanh', 
               return_sequences=True))
    x.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(out_size, activation='softmax')))
    mask= Sequential()
    mask.add(Dense(out_size, input_shape=(seq_len, out_size)))
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Merge([x, mask], mode='mul'))
else:
    # Functional, working
    x = Input((seq_len, input_dim))
    lstm = LSTM(128, return_sequences=True, activation='tanh')(x)
    td = TimeDistributed(Dense(out_size, activation='softmax'))(lstm)
    mask= Input((seq_len, out_size))
    out = merge([td, mask], mode='mul')
    model = Model(input=[x, mask], output=out)

# same in Sequential and Functional
model.compile(...) 
model.fit(...)
```

Comment: Could you show a visualization or at least give numbers for the amount of difference? Did you try to run it more than once. Maybe it is the shuffling of the input data?

Comment: after you compile your `model`, run `model.summary()`, it should show you the difference. or plot it..