# Keras model input syntax, use of plus (+)

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, input, keras, addition

my main question is about the use of "+" when declaring a keras model inputs /outputs,
how is this different from the normal `[input1, input2],[output1,output2]` method?
for example [in this lstm seq2seq inference model](https://blog.keras.io/a-ten-minute-introduction-to-sequence-to-sequence-learning-in-keras.html):
afer having trained the model, the author defines the inference model:

```python
decoder_model = Model(
[decoder_inputs] + decoder_states_inputs,
[decoder_outputs] + decoder_states)
```

I can't find any example like this in the keras documentation.

If you want to know the specifics of my problem: i'm working on a: CNN for feature extraction ->  GRU layer (gives states) -> GRU layer -> Dense layer architecture for performing OCR on images.
**my prototype trains just fine**, but when i try to declare the inference model similar to the example above, i get an error for adding inputs of differing dimensions, yet the example above also has differing dimensions.

here is my inference model:

```python
decoder_state_input = Input(shape=(deencoder_dims,))

decoder_outputs, state_h = decoder_gru(
    decoder_input, initial_state=decoder_state_input)

decoder_outputs = decoder_dense(decoder_outputs)

decoder_model = Model(
    [decoder_input] + decoder_state_input,
    [decoder_outputs] + state_h)
```

with the in/outputs:

```python
decoder_input = (None,83) (num of decoder tokens)
decoder_state_input = (None,100) (states)
decoder_outputs = (None,83) (tokens)
decoder_states = (None,100) (states)
```

Which results in error: `InvalidArgumentError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 83 and 100 for 'add_1' (op: 'Add') with input shapes: [1,?,?,83], [?,100].`
Not sure where the 1 in [1,?,?,83] comes from...

and this is the code from the example:

```python
decoder_state_input_h = Input(shape=(latent_dim,))
decoder_state_input_c = Input(shape=(latent_dim,))
decoder_states_inputs = [decoder_state_input_h, decoder_state_input_c]
decoder_outputs, state_h, state_c = decoder_lstm(
    decoder_inputs, initial_state=decoder_states_inputs)
decoder_states = [state_h, state_c]
decoder_outputs = decoder_dense(decoder_outputs)
decoder_model = Model(
    [decoder_inputs] + decoder_states_inputs,
    [decoder_outputs] + decoder_states)
```

which runs fine.

I don't see why the inputs should be declared like this, nor can i find anything in the documentation to explain it. i understand that the error pops up when i try to do this, since the inputs are of differing dimensions, yet the same doesn't happen for the example!? It also has inputs of differing sizes, here's the summary for the inference model in the example:

```python
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_12 (InputLayer)           (None, None, 83)     0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
input_13 (InputLayer)           (None, 100)          0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
input_14 (InputLayer)           (None, 100)          0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
lstm_4 (LSTM)                   [(None, None, 100),  73600       input_12[0][0]                   
                                                                 input_13[0][0]                   
                                                                 input_14[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_6 (Dense)                 (None, None, 83)     8383        lstm_4[1][0]                     
==================================================================================================
```

Thanks for any insight you might have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, so basically the "+" is applying the keras ADD merge layer to the inputs. this is apparently the only way to add new inputs to an existing graph, this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42804966/convert-sequential-to-functional-in-keras#42808714) gave me the hint. 
The second problem was that you cannot add inputs of differing dimensions, this however can be circumvented by declaring your input as a list `input1 = [Input(something)]`, you also cannnot do this when declaring your inputs at `model = Model(Input = ...)`, i don't know why, but it didn't work for me.

My working code looks like this:

```
decoder_state_input = [Input(shape=(deencoder_dims,))]
decoder_outputs, state_h = decoder_gru(
    decoder_input, initial_state=decoder_state_input)
state_h_out = [state_h]
decoder_outputs = decoder_dense(decoder_outputs)
decoder_model = Model(
    [decoder_input]+decoder_state_input,
    [decoder_outputs]+state_h_out
)
model.summary()
```

Notice the inputs are declared as lists.

In conclusion:

- Declaring new inputs/outputs to attach to existing graphs: need to be declared as list and merged with previous inputs (no idea how keras separates them... )
- keras doesn't always make sense :)